# Colouring A Cube

Tags: combinatorics, coloring, algebraic-graph-theory

How many distinct ways are there of coloring the faces of a cube with k colors such
that adjacent faces are colored with different colors considering that two colorings are the
same if they are equivalent by motions of the cube.

To go through with this will i need to consider all 24 rotations of a cube?
This cube would need at least three colours, what confuses me is k colours like how do i approach such graph theoretical question.

Comment: Whether you consider the rotation depends on what the question is specifically, a good first step would be to convert the cube to a 2d graph with each side being a vertex.

Comment: Thats for not distinct

Comment: I have not read your question properly either https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem#Colored_cubes ... you want adjacent faces to be distinct $\ddot \smile$